# SASS Problem with npm scripts ( autoprefix and postcss )

Tags: sass, postcss, autoprefixer

My compilation process does not work and as I am a beginner I do not know why. Any constructive help is highly appreciated ;).

I have spent like 24 hours to solve the problem without success...
I have reinstalled all packages, cleaned cache etc., but nothing has helped.

```
     {
  "name": "natours",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Landing page for natours",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w",
    "devserver": "live-server",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel devserver watch:sass",
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css",
    "concat:css": "concat -o css/style.concat.css css/icon-font.css css/style.comp.css",
    "prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last ten versions' css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css",
    "compress:css": "node-sass css/style.prefix.css css/style.css --output-style compressed",
    "build:css": "npm-run-all compile:sass concat:css prefix:css compress:css"
  },
  "author": "Jonas",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.0",
    "concat": "^1.0.3",
    "libs": "^0.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss": "^8.0.5",
    "postcss-cli": "^7.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "live-server": "^1.2.1"
  }
}
```

When I run command npm run prefix:css I get such error:

```
npm run prefix:css

> natours@1.0.0 prefix:css /home/piotr/Documents/personal/ProgrammingBooks/HTML, CSS/advanced-css-course-master/Natours/starter
> postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last ten versions' css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css

Error: PostCSS plugin autoprefixer requires PostCSS 8. Update PostCSS or downgrade this plugin.
    at Processor.normalize (/home/piotr/Documents/personal/ProgrammingBooks/HTML, CSS/advanced-css-course-master/Natours/starter/node_modules/postcss-cli/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:167:15)
    at new Processor (/home/piotr/Documents/personal/ProgrammingBooks/HTML, CSS/advanced-css-course-master/Natours/starter/node_modules/postcss-cli/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:56:25)
    at postcss (/home/piotr/Documents/personal/ProgrammingBooks/HTML, CSS/advanced-css-course-master/Natours/starter/node_modules/postcss-cli/node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.js:55:10)
    at /home/piotr/Documents/personal/ProgrammingBooks/HTML, CSS/advanced-css-course-master/Natours/starter/node_modules/postcss-cli/index.js:216:14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! natours@1.0.0 prefix:css: `postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last ten versions' css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the natours@1.0.0 prefix:css script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/piotr/.npm/_logs/2020-09-18T21_58_54_802Z-debug.log

-------------
I also add COMPLETE LOG ERROR

0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/home/piotr/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/piotr/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'prefix:css'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v12.18.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prefix:css' ]
5 info lifecycle natours@1.0.0~prefix:css: natours@1.0.0
6 verbose lifecycle natours@1.0.0~prefix:css: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle natours@1.0.0~prefix:css: PATH: /home/piotr/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/piotr/Documents/personal/ProgrammingBooks/HTML, CSS/advanced-css-course-master/Natours/starter/node_modules/.bin:/home/piotr/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
8 verbose lifecycle natours@1.0.0~prefix:css: CWD: /home/piotr/Documents/personal/ProgrammingBooks/HTML, CSS/advanced-css-course-master/Natours/starter
9 silly lifecycle natours@1.0.0~prefix:css: Args: [
9 silly lifecycle   '-c',
9 silly lifecycle   "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last ten versions' css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css"
9 silly lifecycle ]
10 silly lifecycle natours@1.0.0~prefix:css: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
11 info lifecycle natours@1.0.0~prefix:css: Failed to exec prefix:css script
12 verbose stack Error: natours@1.0.0 prefix:css: `postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last ten versions' css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css`
12 verbose stack Exit status 1
12 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/piotr/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
12 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/piotr/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
13 verbose pkgid natours@1.0.0
14 verbose cwd /home/piotr/Documents/personal/ProgrammingBooks/HTML, CSS/advanced-css-course-master/Natours/starter
15 verbose Linux 5.4.0-47-generic
16 verbose argv "/home/piotr/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/bin/node" "/home/piotr/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/bin/npm" "run" "prefix:css"
17 verbose node v12.18.3
18 verbose npm  v6.14.8
19 error code ELIFECYCLE
20 error errno 1
21 error natours@1.0.0 prefix:css: `postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last ten versions' css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css`
21 error Exit status 1
22 error Failed at the natours@1.0.0 prefix:css script.
22 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
23 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Hi not sure, perhaps PostCSS package needs to be installed?

Comment: As you can see, it has already been installed. But thanks for your effort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue - there seems to be some bugs with [autoprefixer version 10.0.0](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/issues/1359).

Downgrade your autoprefixer vesion and your command will run as expected.

Change `"autoprefixer": "^10.0.0",` to `"autoprefixer": "<10.0.0",` in your package file. This will install the newest version of autoprefixer that is less than version 10.0.0 - [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25861938).

Comment: Yes, it is the right answer. I downgraded autoprefixer to 9.8.6 and all work correctly now.

Comment: @AlexanderSchneider don't forget to mark the answer as correct (the checkmark under it) if it solves the issue. Glad it worked out for you!